# "content_scripts" not working in chrome v38+?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Recently, I made a Chrome Extension to force all webpages to use given font. It used to work just fine but stopped working since yesterday (maybe earlier).

Key codes for the extension are:

> **`manifest.json` file content:**
>
> ```
> {
>     ...
>
>     "content_scripts": [{
>         "matches":  ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
>         "js": ["font.js"],
>         "run_at":"document_start"
>     }],
>     "web_accessible_resources": ["font.css"]
> }
> ```
>
> **`font.js` file content:**
>
> ```
> var link = document.createElement("link");
> link.href = chrome.extension.getURL("font.css");
> link.type = "text/css";
> link.rel = "stylesheet";
> document.documentElement.insertBefore(link);
> ```
>
> **`font.css` file content:**
>
> ```
> * {
>   font-family: "Microsoft Yahei Mono", "Microsoft Yahei", sans-serif !important; 
> }
> ```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here or suggest alternative ways to run the `js` file while starting the webpage documents?

Comment: -1: "Stopped working" and no code, sorry, but this is impossible to answer. Please include your code.

Comment: Provide us the code of your content script, otherwise it's impossible to know what's causing the error. Most of the times, when running in `document_start`, scripts stop working because some elements haven't been loaded yet... but it's impossible to say without seeing your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Chrome 38, Chrome follows the DOM standard and throws an exception when `.insertBefore` omits the required argument (see https://crbug.com/419780).

To fix your code, either use

```
document.documentElement.insertBefore(link, null);
// or equivalently,
document.documentElement.appendChild(link);
```

I recommend to use the [`"css"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#css) key instead of a content script to insert the style sheets. Then you don't need `font.js` any more (and the style sheet will also be applied immediately upon install).

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "my extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":  ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "css": ["font.css"],
        "run_at":"document_start"
    }]
}
```

Comment: fyi: I actually need to use `font.js` as I will further need to allow several webpages to use its original font.